# How to use nodejs argument in subprocess supervisord environment from docker

Tags: node.js, docker, environment-variables, supervisord

Using Docker run --env, I set ARGUMENT=yes.

In supervisord.conf:

```
program:service]
command=/usr/bin/node /service/service.js argument=%(ENV_ARGUMENT)s
stdout_logfile=/service/service.out
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

I need to run nodejs argument using environment variable that passed from docker run --env and through supervisord environment.

Using `%(ENV_ARGUMENT)s` (Docker not running), `%(ARGUMENT)s` (Docker not running) or `$ARGUMENT` (it will retrieve as string $ARGUMENT not yes) not working.

Is there any proper way to using supervisord environment to nodejs argument?

Comment: The correct format is `%(ENV_ARGUMENT)s`. What happens when you use this?

Comment: Docker container will not run. No container running when using docker ps.

Comment: use `docker run -it -e ARGUMENT=yes <imagename>` and see if you get any errors?

Comment: No error coming out. Using script to run docker container and then use docker ps for a while is running then manually running docker ps the container is disappears. But I have the solution for this. Using this in command `command=/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/node /service/service.js argument=$ARGUMENT"` work fine as using bash environment variable passed from docker.